# Mapping parent child relationships in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table with 2 columns in Google BigQuery. PARENT and CHILD. I am trying to show all child relationships to the parent.

```
 CHILD  PARENT
B        A
C        A
D        A
B1       B
B2       B
D1       D
E1       D1
E2       D1
```

The output should be

```
CHILD   PARENT
B         A
B1        A
B2        A
C         A
D         A
D1        A
E1        A
E2        A
B1        B
B2        B
D1        D
E1        D
E2        D
E1        D1
E2        D1
```

This is the query I’ve written

```
SELECT CHILD, PARENT
FROM TREE 
UNION ALL 
SELECT x.PARENT, x.CHILD
FROM TREE x INNER JOIN TREE Y 
ON X.PARENT = Y.CHILD
) 
SELECT * FROM x
```

My output is incorrect. Each other the parent product should have all the child product (and child of child tied to them)

```
CHILD   PARENT
B        A
C        A
D          A
B1        B
B2        B
D1        D
E1        D1
E2        D1
B1        B
B2        B
D1        D
E1        D1
E2        D1
```

I believe I should be using a recursive CTE.

Comment: BQ does not (yet) allow for recursive CTEs.  Do you know the depth of your hierarchy? If so, you can use N CTEs/Subqueries.  If not, your best bet might be checking out BQ scripting https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting and use a loop.

Comment: The root is A for this model

Comment: So the relationship of A->B would be 2 levels of hierarchy, while E1->D1->D->A is 4 levels.  Do you know the max depth?  If you know that you could write a specific query (might be long, but would work).  If that can depth can vary as new children are added, then i think you will need to take the scripting route.